# Django Compare Foreign Key Value to Attribute of another Model

Tags: python, django

I'm still relatively new to Django, but I decided to try to build a personal portfolio of personal projects I've worked on. I've set it up so that you land on the home page. From there, you can click on a language. Then if I've used a framework for that language, I want to display it to the screen or if I have a project I did not using a framework in that language, it would be displayed here as well. To do this, I've set up a foreign key from frameworks to languages and from JobNoFramework to Language. I have put in a framework object for Django to test it. If I change the comparison operator to `!=`, it displays, but as soon as I make it `==` it doesn't work, even though if I say `{{frameworks.language}} - {{languages.language}}` I get Python - Python. I'd really appreciate any help.

Here's the relevant code:

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
# Create your models here.
class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language

class Framework(models.Model):
    framework = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.framework

class JobNoFramework(models.Model):
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    submissionDate = models.DateField(default = date.today, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job + "\n" + self.summary

class JobYesFramework(models.Model):
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    framework = models.ForeignKey(Framework, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    submissionDate = models.DateField(default = date.today, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job + "\n" + self.summary
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Framework, Language, JobNoFramework, JobYesFramework

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    languages = Language.objects
    return render(request, 'jobs/home.html',{'languages':languages})

def lang_detail(request, lang_id):
    language = get_object_or_404(Language, pk=lang_id)
    projects = JobNoFramework.objects
    frameworks = Framework.objects
    return render(request, 'jobs/language.html', {'languages':language, "projects":projects, "frameworks":frameworks})
```

Template:

```
<div class="row">
            {% for frameworks in frameworks.all %}
            {% if frameworks.language == languages.language %} <!-- need help with this line -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">

                  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ frameworks.image.url }}"> <!-- need to add image field -->
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <center>

                      <p class="card-text">{{ frameworks.framework }}</p>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```py
frameworks.language.language == languages.language
```

When you do `{{frameworks.language}} - {{languages.language}}` you have `frameworks.language` converted to string, that why it showed 'Python - Python'. In your condition though you were comparing an object Language to a string which was always false of course.

Comment: Yep that was it, thank you so much. I'll accept your answer as correct when it allows me to